# Example or plugin to anonymize FHIR Json

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a set of health care information in FHIR json format. Before storing such sensitive information i would like to anonymize the sensitive information such as name , phone number, address, physician contacts, etc.

I googled about anonimizing the fhir json and found there exist some security labels which classifies the information as Confidential , restricted , etc - https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-security-labels.html

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-auditevent-anonymized.html - This talks about the extension and the structure of anonymized data.

I am not sure how to replace these variables with security codes. Is there any api which does that or i have to find all the tags which are sensitive and loop the json and replace tags with security code.

Can someone give me an example of this can be achieved.

i have attached a sample json which i generated via synthea

```
{
  "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:7a534e34-40a2-48ab-bc92-066d23251a8b",
  "resource": {
    "resourceType": "Patient",
    "id": "7a534e34-40a2-48ab-bc92-066d23251a8b",
    "text": {
      "status": "generated",
      "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Generated by <a href=\"https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea\">Synthea</a>.Version identifier: v2.5.0-378-gee8c6470\n .   Person seed: 6477291342685874262  Population seed: 1586936726889</div>"
    },
    "extension": [
      {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-mothersMaidenName",
        "valueString": "Hilma831 Luettgen772"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-birthPlace",
        "valueAddress": {
          "city": "Boston",
          "state": "Massachusetts",
          "country": "US"
        }
      },
      {
        "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/disability-adjusted-life-years",
        "valueDecimal": 3.3178400761167306
      },
      {
        "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/quality-adjusted-life-years",
        "valueDecimal": 71.68215992388328
      }
    ],
    "identifier": [
      {
        "system": "https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea",
        "value": "7a534e34-40a2-48ab-bc92-066d23251a8b"
      },
      {
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
              "code": "MR",
              "display": "Medical Record Number"
            }
          ],
          "text": "Medical Record Number"
        },
        "system": "http://hospital.smarthealthit.org",
        "value": "7a534e34-40a2-48ab-bc92-066d23251a8b"
      },
      {
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
              "code": "SS",
              "display": "Social Security Number"
            }
          ],
          "text": "Social Security Number"
        },
        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
        "value": "999-80-4232"
      },
      {
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
              "code": "DL",
              "display": "Driver's License"
            }
          ],
          "text": "Driver's License"
        },
        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.4.3.25",
        "value": "S99911013"
      },
      {
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
              "code": "PPN",
              "display": "Passport Number"
            }
          ],
          "text": "Passport Number"
        },
        "system": "http://standardhealthrecord.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/passportNumber",
        "value": "X66843459X"
      }
    ],
    "name": [
      {
        "use": "official",
        "family": "Kreiger457",
        "given": [
          "Anthony633"
        ],
        "prefix": [
          "Mr."
        ]
      }
    ],
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "555-660-2614",
        "use": "home"
      }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "birthDate": "1939-12-25",
    "deceasedDateTime": "2015-02-02T22:36:55+05:30",
    "address": [
      {
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation",
            "extension": [
              {
                "url": "latitude",
                "valueDecimal": 42.11942297974089
              },
              {
                "url": "longitude",
                "valueDecimal": -71.21834679934824
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "line": [
          "496 Tromp Mews Unit 96"
        ],
        "city": "Walpole",
        "state": "Massachusetts",
        "postalCode": "02081",
        "country": "US"
      }
    ],
    "maritalStatus": {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-MaritalStatus",
          "code": "M",
          "display": "M"
        }
      ],
      "text": "M"
    },
    "multipleBirthBoolean": false,
    "communication": [
      {
        "language": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "urn:ietf:bcp:47",
              "code": "en-US",
              "display": "English"
            }
          ],
          "text": "English"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "Patient"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'standard' way to anonymize because anonymization is a risk-reduction approach that requires knowledge of both the threats you're trying to defend against and how the data needs to be used.  When combined with other data, any element could potentially be 'sensitive'.  It could also be essential to the intended analysis.

The extension you're looking at is specific to audit event.  The way you'd actually flag a Patient resource as having been anonymized is using the ANONYED security tag in resource.meta.  I don't believe there's a standard extension for marking what elements *should* be anonymized.  If there were such an element, the element would also need to indicated *how* the data should be anonymized and the alorithm would typically need to take into account multiple elements - or even multiple resources.  E.g. Should dates be changed to a random value, or just have the day shifted?  Should all dates in the set of related resources be shifted by the same amount or should they be adjusted independently.  If you're changing the practitioners pointed to by different resources, should they be left as is, each one changed randomly, the same practitioner changed to the same random practitioner?